# Defining custom actions in Selenium

Tags: unit-testing, selenium

I have a Selenium test case that enters dates into a date selector made up of three pulldowns (year, month, and day).

```
select validity_Y label=2008
select validity_M label=08
select validity_D label=08
```

This part gets repeated a lot throughout the test case. I'd like to reduce it by defining my custom action "selectValidity", so that I can have less redundancy, something like

```
selectValidity 2008,08,08
```

What is the best (easiest, cleanest) way to add macros or subroutines to a test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're coding your tests in [Selenese](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/selenese.html). If so, have you considered using one of the client drivers in any one of many languages? They've got [java](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/java.html), [.net](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/dotnet.html), [perl](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/perl.html), [ruby](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/ruby.html), [javascript](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/js.html), [php](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/php.html), and [python](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/python.html). Each and every one of them have subroutines. Supposedly, the [IDE](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/selenium-ide/) can translate your existing Selenese tests into most of these.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to define your helper JS functions in a JS file and include it as a core extension or as part of user-extensions.js (as it is done for [UI-Elements](http://ttwhy.org/code/ui-doc.html)). A JS function called selectValidity could then use DOM to select the values.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. But I will probably move on to Selenium RC and Java, as suggested by @sblundy.